# Data format to pass through different scripts/language(perl, python,c++)

Tags: c++, json, perl, tcl

Currently, I need to pass the result of one script language to another. For example, I want to get result of tcl script and pass that result to perl script to continue.

The result data is not regular, meaning not like CSV format. I can certainly use JSON format to pass around but I don't want to(Reason described later). So my question is that, besides JSON format, is there other popular format to pass these non-regular documentation-like data through different script language?

The reason I don't want to use JSON format is:

1. The current package for JSON format is reading in the whole JSON data. Sometimes my data is too huge that I have to read block by block. For example following data:

   ```
   [
    { key: a0,
      value: b0
    },
    ...
    { key: a999999,
      value: b999999
    }
   ]
   ```
2. I don't JSON parser package for my script. And I don't have the permission to install them. So I am looking other format as the replacement.

Thanks

Comment: You could start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data_serialization_formats Personally, I would probably go for xml in your situation.

Comment: Another popular format is XML. There are libraries for streaming processing (SAX or pull-parsers).

Comment: If you don't have permissions to use CPAN modules then you are severly restricting your options when using Perl. I strongly recommend that you work on fixing this problem and get yourself an environment where you can use the power of CPAN.

Comment: Your second reason is basically bunk, you know? Just copy the package/module code into your own and accept that you're doing something horrible, forced by the awkward situation that you're in. (It happens. We might wish it didn't, but it does.)

Comment: Is your data describable as a (large!) collection of key-value pairs? Perhaps with complex keys, but even so? Is the size of individual pairs fairly small, but with a very large number of them? If so, streaming is quite simple and many formats can be used. If you're streaming very large complex-structured data, life gets… _difficult_, shall we say? **tl;dr** You need to specify what you are looking for more precisely for this to be a reasonable Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 0):

[YAML](http://yaml.org/) would be another choice, parsers for many languages are available.

Your example, a sequence of maps, would look like

```
---
-
 key: a0
 value: b0
- 
 ...
-
 key: a999999
 value: b999999
```

Comment: But are there any YAML parsers which can read and process the file block by block, rather than loading it all into memory?